# .htaccess redirect to suborder based on cookie

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I have two folders in my website root directory en and te.
I need to write .htaccess file that redirects request to en/ if the cookie language=en
or redirect to /te of if language!=en or cookie language is not set.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cookie/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} language=te [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /te [L]
```

but the above code not working

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you want to redirect the user , or rewrite the url internally (remove R=301) :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} language=(en|te) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(te|en)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not redirect the user, as you have left out the appropriate rewrite flag. Instead, it will just rewrite the request (silently, on the server) without changing the url.

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /te/$1 [R=301]
```

(You were also not appending the route for the page to the language key - I have also appended the `$1`.)